# How to display search results as a list in jsp page?

Tags: java, database, jsp, jakarta-ee, gridview

I am new to jsp and javaEE and trying to do the following: I do a database search and find all accounts of a user. Then i want to list them, in asp.net gridview is a very useful tool for this, we can add checkboxes, buttons and so on to the gridview to the all rows, and add specific events to these rows. What is the way to do this in java? Should i install an extension? Here is my code:

```
try {
        connect();
        PreparedStatement checkDB = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM Accounts where username = ?");
        checkDB.setString(1,username);
        ResultSet rs =null;
        rs=(ResultSet) checkDB.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {

            //LIST THE RESULTS AS A GRIDVIEW HERE
            rs.close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            rs.close();
            System.out.println("awwwwww");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cannot connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of what kind of thing i want:

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @StefanBeike what do you mean?

Comment: i have seen an example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7813/Data-Grid-for-JSP but the tag <grd: ... > does not work there is no such tag in my eclipse this is why i wonder should i install an extension for grid or is there a built in standart one?

Comment: do you want to call the database from your jsp directly? First of all introduce yourself into an easy MVC tutorial. There are a couple of Hello World tutorials using Servlet's and JSP's

Answer (score 1):

Your Servlet can dispatch a JSP to display the results after you save the data you want to display into a session or request object.

You can get a similar look with the tag library [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/).
For instance, the code below was used to generate http://nciml.mathteamhosting.com/generated/topStudents.htm

```
    <%-- At top of page --%>
    <%@taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>

   <display:table id="row" name="rankedList" >
    <display:column property="rank" title="Rank"  />
    <display:column property="firstName" title="First" />
    <display:column property="lastName" title="Last"  />
    <display:column property="mySchool" title="School" />
    <display:column property="c1" title="C1" />
    <display:column property="c2" title="C2" />
    <display:column property="c3" title="C3" />
    <display:column property="c4" title="C4" />
    <display:column property="c5" title="C5" />
    <display:column property="cTotal" title="Total Points" />
</display:table>
```

In the above code, rankedList is an ArrayList of RankedStudent which is a POJO with the properties listed. You must have public getters and setters for every property you want to use with displayTag.

Comment: You need to include the jar file in your project. Download & unzip it and save in your project's lib folder if you aren't using maven. http://sourceforge.net/projects/displaytag/files/

Answer (score 0):

You can use table tag of html to display the result that you have given in screenshot.

```
<table> <tr><th>heading</th><th>heading</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr>

if(rs.next())
    {
          <tr>
                <td>data</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
          </tr>



    }
```

rs.close();

Answer (score 0):

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList aListOfBeans;
    try {
        connect();
        PreparedStatement checkDB = (PreparedStatement) con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Accounts where username = ?");
        checkDB.setString(1, username);
        rs = (ResultSet) checkDB.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            if (aListOfBeans == null)
                aListOfBeans = new ArrayList();
            // LIST THE RESULTS AS A GRIDVIEW HERE
            String crn = rs.getString("CRN");
            String courseCode = rs.getString("COURSE_CODE");
            // etc etc etc (for all the columns)

            MyAccountBean aBean = new MyAccountBean();
            aBean.setCRN(crn);
            aBean.setCourseCode(courseCode);
            // etc etc etc

            aListOfBeans.add(aBean);
        }

        if (aListOfBeans == null) {
            System.out.println("awwwwww");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cannot connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();
        // closing rs, con, checkDB in finally block *ensures* they get
        // closed even if Exception is caught
        // i didn't write for the others, but you get the idea
    }
    return aListOfBeans;
```

Ideally the above code should be in your Java servlet, not on your JSP page. Your JSP should only show the data, not do DB connections or fetch it from DB.

Later in your JSP, get the ArrayList aListOfBeans from the session, and use getter methods on the beans (`aBean.getCRN()`) to get the data. Use a for loop on the ArrayList to dynamically generate your table.